# Why does a browser concatenate the href when I set it dynamically?

Tags: php, html, href

I am working on a language switcher, and I use PHP to change the URL from a language to another. I want the language switching button (i.e.  link) to change its href attribute when the page loads. Here's my code:

```
<?php

$actual_link = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (strpos($actual_link, 'fr') !== false) {
    $actual_lang = 'fr';
    $new_link = str_replace('/fr/','/en/',$actual_link);
}
else {
    $actual_lang = 'en';
    $new_link = str_replace('/en/','/fr/',$actual_link);
}

echo "

<div class='top-bar'>
    <a class='language-selector' id='language-switch-btn' href='#'>Language</a>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('language-switch-btn').href = '".$new_link."';
</script>

";
?>
```

However, my problem is that the JS code concatenates the $new_link to the $actual_link, resulting in the href attribute like this: localhost/website.com/fr/localhost/website.com/en/ when I would want it to be only localhost/website.com/en/

Any idea why it doesn't replace '#' by $newlink ? Thank you

Comment: If this is a JavaScript question, you should share the generated JavaScript code, not the source PHP. But I can't see how `.href = 'blah'` could possibly concatenate. Have you verified what your PHP variables contain?

Comment: It does but without a protocol `localhost/website.com/en/` is a relative path starting from the current folder

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript at all here? Just `echo "<a href='".%new_link."'>Language</a>"`!

Comment: @Bergi Because I'm a newbie. Excellent suggestion, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` doesn't include the *protocol*, and without the protocol links are relative.

You can prefix the `href` with `//` to allow any http protocol (either http or https), but as mentioned in the comment you also don't need JS to do this.

```
echo "
<div class='top-bar'>
  <a class='language-selector'
     id='language-switch-btn'
     href='//".$new_link."'>Language</a>
</div>
";
```

Comment: Alternatively, drop the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` from the link and just make it an absolute path

Comment: yeah, I just guessed there was a reason to have the host in, but fair point